# Excepcion: java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Tags: java, xml, weblogic

Al hacer el despliegue de mi Aplicación Web en el *WebLogic* manda el siguiente error:

> excepcion  java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistrySAXParserFactory cannot be cast to
>   javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Alguien por favor podría orientarme cual puede ser el motivo de esta excepcion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razón básica es que las clases no son compatibles. Normalmente éste conflicto es por el archivo `xml-apis.jar` que se auto-incluye con ciertas herramientas de ensamblaje de artefactos, como maven o ant. Si estás usando maven quita la referencia a `xml-apis.jar`. Si no usas maven, asegúrate de que no aparezca dentro de tu artefacto (archivo .war) en el directorio `WEB-INF/lib/`.

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>biblioteca-que-usa-xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>artefacto</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      ...
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>  <!-- pon aquí la clase que quieres excluir -->
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.01</version>
        </exclusion>
      ...
      </exclusions> 
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, tienes razon por algun motivo que desconosco se esta inclyendo esa libreria al momento de generar el war. Pero efectivamente es esa la que marca el error.

Comment: @jose Se incluye porque es una dependencia secundaria. Otro archivo jar la está usando y no especifica el alcance "scope" como "provided", "runtime" o "compile" para que se excluya del ensamblado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @egallardo ya lo he solicionado.